# Uninstall Mono, .NET Core and all related stuffs from OSX

Tags: .net, macos, mono, dnu, dnvm

Hei guys, i was following this tutorial in order to run .NET Core in my OSX:

```
If you choose to install Mono, select the universal installer to make sure you get the x64 version. Edge.js requires Mono x64.

If you choose to install CoreCLR], follow these steps:

brew tap aspnet/dnx
brew update
brew install dnvm
source dnvm.sh
dnvm install latest -r coreclr -alias edge-coreclr
Then install and build Edge.js:

brew install pkg-config
dnvm use edge-coreclr
npm install edge
```

Now, i would like to remove all this stuffs, but i'm not finding the paths.

I removed the `dnvm` and the `pkg-config` with `brew uninstall`. What about the orders?

Thanks.